# What LayoutManager should I use for a RecyclerView to avoid distributing cards evenly?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

*tl;dr:*  What do I need to do to get the result from the first image instead of the second one (concerning the blue squares)?

---

First, the code snippets are at https://gist.github.com/exhuma/125ec8a5e32b395fd786
and an image for reference, representing the intended outcome:

[image: intended outcome]

I have an application with 3 RecyclerViews. One "main" list in the center, and two "status views" to the left and right of it. The main list works as intended, and it should be scrollable. The ones to the left and right have cards which will rarely (if ever) fill the whole screen height. Scrolling would be a nice-to-have, but is not necessary. They both represent sort of a "pending queue" of items which will soon appear in the main list, visualised with small icons.

I tried just going about the business in the same way as I did for the central view. But when I did that, it resulted in the cards in the "queue" lists to be evenly spaced like this:

[image: this is not what I want]

My question is: **What LayoutManager does this?** Or should I use something else than the `RecyclerView` instead? Like a `ListView`?

Comment: Can you post your layout xml and a code snippet detailing your current LayoutManagers?

Comment: Added the code here: https://gist.github.com/exhuma/125ec8a5e32b395fd786

Comment: Several initial thoughts - try changing the height of each of your recycler views on the sides to wrap_content instead of match_parent. Second, would be to change your list items parent object's height to wrap_content. Third would be to set the gravity of the recycler_view to top.

Comment: Unfortunately, none of the 3 solutions worked :(

Comment: I'll try and lay some things out myself and play with it when I have a little more time. Unfortunately I haven't messed a whole lot with RecyclerViews, but I'll post back if I find a solution.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. It might be, that this is not something Recyclers are meant to be used for. I actually have no clue ;) And maybe a simple `ListView` would do. AFAICT, Recyclers are useful for better performance with long lists. Which is not the case here. But then again, this is one of my first Android projects, so I am still a bit green behind my ears ;)

Comment: If there are an indeterminate number of elements in each list, then yes, the recylcerview or listview would be appropriate. However, if they are going to stay the same, or if there are only a few static elements that you may need to toggle the visibility on, then you should just create a static layout. In the first case, a listview will probably be totally acceptable.

Comment: In this case, it is indeterminate (something between 0 and 40), so I'll stick with something like the `ListView` or `RecyclerView`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to force the cards of the RecyclerView to a fixed size. Replace this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@id/statusIcon"
        android:maxHeight="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

With this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@id/statusIcon"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Obviously, this will not scale with screen sizes. There still might be a better solution. This works for now...